# HSPLL mode freezes 18F46K20 micro controller

Tags: pll, xc8

COMPILER: XC8 v 1.30
micro: PIC18F46K20

I use this in CONFIG1H register to get 64MHz Fosc (and use PLL):

```
#pragma config FOSC = INTIO7 // 1001 = Internal oscillator block, CLKOUT 
                             // function on RA6, port function on RA7
OSCON.IDLEN = 1;    // 16 MHz (HFINTOSC drives clock directly)
OSCON.IRCF = 111;
OSCON.SCS = 00; // Primary clock (determined by   CONFIG1H[FOSC<3:0>]).
OSCTUNE.PLLEN = 1;  // enable PLL for 8 and 16MHz Fosc
```

And then uC runs at 64MHz and I get 64/4=16MHz signal on pin RA6 (as expected)

But when I tried 'HSPLL' - as in data sheet :

```
 #pragma config FOSC = HSPLL // 0110 = HS oscillator, PLL enabled (Clock Frequency = 4 x FOSC1)
```

then it completely STALLS uC : !!! It would not even start after build and power up.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have a crystal connected to the OSC1/OSC2 pins? If you're not using the internal oscillator then you'll need an external clock or crystal.

Comment: So HSPLL is an option for external OSC ? I didn't see that in data sheet.

Comment: Thank you. So HSPLL is an option for external OSC ? I didn't see that in data sheet. Figure 2.1 on page 27 of PIC18F46K20 shows that PLL can be applied to internal Osc.

Comment: Yes, HS means you are using a crystal. HSPLL means the crystal signal is fed to the PLL. These alternatives are selected by configuration fuses. LFINTOSC means you are using the internal oscillator and, if int osc is running at 8 or 16 MHz, you can turn the PLL on or off in software by setting the PLLEN bit.

Comment: Thanks, user manual for that micro in this area is quite confusing in my opinion. I will hook external OSC or SigGen to the uC and see if all works then.

Answer (score 1):

[Page 31 of the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41303G.pdf) has a section called "2.4.3 LP, XT, HS MODES".  It has a diagram which shows the necessary external circuitry.  By using HSPLL you are then using the HS mode with the PLL.

Page 27 has the following diagram, which I think is more helpful generally:

[image]

Then you know to what the macros are referring.